# Skip Function repeating values while appending in View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to use skip in mvc4 project so that previous value should not repeated while it append in the Razor view but i am getting same value after some value

here is my code :

```
var planetfeedsOrder = from a in db.PlanetFeeds
                       where a.PlanetFeedOwnerId == id || a.PlanetFeedPosterId ==id
                         && a.CurrentState != 1
                       join c in db.Graphs on a.PlanetFeedItemGraphId equals c.GraphID
                       join u in db.UserInfos on a.PlanetFeedOwnerId equals u.UserInfoID
                       orderby a.PostDate descending
                       select new UserInfoViewModel
                       {
                           AvatarURL = u.AvatarURL,
                           UserName=u.FirstName +" "+u.LastName,
                           GraphItemDescription = c.GraphItemDescription,
                           GraphItemURL = c.GraphItemURL,
                           GraphItemUserFullName = c.GraphItemUserFullName,
                           ItemSummary = c.ItemSummary,
                           GraphItemThumbUrl = c.GraphItemThumbUrl,
                           GraphID = c.GraphID,
                           ItemType = c.ItemType,
                           ItemUserID = c.ItemUserID,
                           GraphItemTitle = c.GraphItemTitle,
                           isRootFeed = a.isRootFeed,
                           PostDate = a.PostDate,
                           CommentCount = c.CountResponses,
                           CountReactions = c.CountPositiveReactions,
                           CountReaction = c.CountNegativeReactions,
                           ItemID = c.ItemID,
                           UserLevel =u.UserLevel,
                           CurrentState = a.CurrentState,
                           RecieverUserAvatarURL = c.Address
                       };
return PartialView("_PlanetfeedPartial", planetfeedsOrder.Skip(SkipCount).Take(itemCount).ToList());
```

and here is ajax view where i am trying to append it :

```
$.ajax(
{
    type: "Post",
    url: "/PlanetFeed/PlanetfeedPartial",
    dataType: "html",
    data: { id: planetFeedOwnerId, filterType: filterType, taggedItemGraphId: taggedItemGraphId, itemCount: itemCount,skipCount: SkipCount },      //"feedGraphId=10696",
    success: function (data) {                                                                             
        var div = $('.planetFeed:last');
        $('.planetFeed').removeClass('.tile-group');                               
        SkipCount = itemCount+2;                             
        div.after(data);
        var bigDivCount = $('.tile-group').length;
        var bigDivWidth = bigDivCount * 486;
        $('.tile-area').css({ 'width': bigDivWidth });
```

Comment: Please put more effort into formatting the code in your posts. I was able to outdent a lot of the code by a huge amount, so there's much less need to scroll now - something you could have picked up in the preview when you were first posting.

Comment: In your AJAX method you are setting the value `SkipCount = itemCount+2;` so if `itemCount` is fixed (cant see that you update it anywhere) then `SkipCount` always has the same value. I suspect you want to increment it (say) `SkipCount = SkipCount + itemCount;`

Comment: @StephenMuecke i have updated itemcount=itemcount+2 just before this ajax is called

Comment: @StephenMuecke Problem is that i am getting repeatative values to list

Comment: Thats because the way you are setting the values of itemcount and skipcount make no sense (after the 2nd iteration you start repeating values). How many items do you want to return (i.e. what should be the value of `.Take()`

Comment: @StephenMuecke value of take should be 5 in each scroll..i have use bind scroll for window as we scroll mouse itemcount increase by +5

Comment: Try initial settings of `var itemCount = 5; var skipCount = 0;` then in the success function `skipCount += itemCount;` (do not change the value of `itemCount`) - you should not repeat any values

Comment: @StephenMuecke when i scroll the window i want item count to be increased

Comment: So in the first scroll you want to display 5, then next you want 15 (existing 5 + 10), and the next 30 (existing 15 + 15), and the next 50 (existing 30 + 20) etc?

Comment: @StephenMuecke yes Excatly this is the situation and i want last those are append to be skipped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your code and subsequent comments if the initial values of `itemCount` and `skipCount` are zero then in the first call (note I have substituted variables with the actual values in the `data` parameter so its easier to see what will be returned)

```
itemCount  = itemCount + 5; // itemCount = 0 + 5 = 5
data: { skipCount: 0, itemCount: 5 } // returns items 1-5
skipCount = itemCount + 5; // skipCount = 5 + 5 = 10;
```

second call

```
itemCount  = itemCount + 5; // itemCount = 5 + 5 = 10;
data: { skipCount: 10, itemCount: 10 } // returns items 11-20 (items 6-10 missed)
skipCount = itemCount + 5; // skipCount = 10 + 5 = 15;
```

third call

```
itemCount  = itemCount + 5; // itemCount = 10 + 5 = 15;
data: { skipCount: 15, itemCount: 15 } // returns items 16-30 (items 16-20 repeated)
skipCount = itemCount + 5; // skipCount = 15 + 5 = 20;
```

You need to change the way you set the value of skip count and use `skipCount = skipCount + itemCount;`

first call

```
itemCount  = itemCount + 5; // itemCount = 0 + 5 = 5
data: { skipCount: 0, itemCount: 5 } // returns items 1-5
skipCount = skipCount + itemCount; // skipCount = 0 + 5 = 5;
```

second call

```
itemCount  = itemCount + 5; // itemCount = 5 + 5 = 10;
data: { skipCount: 5, itemCount: 10 } // returns items 6-15
skipCount = skipCount + itemCount; // skipCount = 5 + 10 = 15;
```

third call

```
itemCount  = itemCount + 5; // itemCount = 10 + 5 = 15;
data: { skipCount: 15, itemCount: 15 } // returns items 16-30
skipCount = skipCount + itemCount; // skipCount = 15 + 15 = 30;
```

forth call

```
itemCount  = itemCount + 5; // itemCount = 15 + 5 = 20;
data: { skipCount: 30, itemCount: 20 } // returns items 31-50
skipCount = skipCount + itemCount; // skipCount = 30 + 20 = 50;
```

Comment: Can i have your email id ?

Comment: Sir one more help from Your Side.Can you please tell me if i am posting new value from View only it should post before the first item.How should i do this i need some idea

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand what you asking (you haven't posted your view so hard to tell), but it sounds like you should be asking a new question with additional details of what you want to do

Comment: not new Question ..in this view only if i am creating new item it doesn't show there i have to refresh the view so that the item will be shown first according to order by postdate.how can i do this without Refreshing whole page the new item will append at before first item

Comment: So does this view also have a form to add a new item? and is new item added via an ajax call?

Comment: The new item id added by this == : 

  xhr.open('POST', '/PlanetFeed/GetPlanetFeedWithFiles?statusMessage=' + statusMessage + '&caption=' + caption + '&planetfeedOwnerId=' + planetFeedOwnerId + '&feedType=' + feedType + '&taggedItemGraphId=' + taggedItemGraphId);
                    xhr.send(formdata);

Comment: Its late. I think about it in the morning.

Comment: Sir may i have you email..i am new Programmer..want you to be my mentor

Comment: If you showing results for the current user only, then when you add a new item from this view, you can insert the html for the new item at the top of the list and then increment the value of `skipCount` by 1 so that your in sync with the results returned by the query. If you have any further issues, you need to ask a **new** question (that's the rules of SO). And sorry but you cant have my email address